# Is it possible to change a variable in a Javascript file in a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, video.js, tampermonkey

I use udemy.com for learning various things and they use the [videojs](http://videojs.com/) HTML5 player. They changed the default value for rewinding and going forward from 5 to 15 seconds. In my opinion that's just way too much since often I don't understand just a single word or thing that was done and want to go back by 3 seconds at most.
So my question is: is it possible to change that variable in browser or with something like Tampermonkey so that when I use the arrow left or arrow right that it only goes back and forth by 3 seconds and not 15? I found these methods in the [source code](https://www.udemy.com/staticx/udemy/js/webpack/videojs-open-source-package.8c14010d78dd1966a713.js) for rewinding and going forward:

```
    2782: function (t, e, n) {
    "use strict";

    function o(t, e, n) {
        return t.preventDefault(), t.shiftKey && e.speedDown ? (e.speedDown(), "speeddown") : e.seekBackward ? (e.seekBackward(n.seekStep), "rewind") : void 0
    }

    function i(t, e, n) {
        return t.preventDefault(), t.shiftKey && e.speedUp ? (e.speedUp(), "speedup") : e.seekForward ? (e.seekForward(n.seekStep), "forward") : void 0
    }
```

The variable "seekStep" is set here:

```
var f = (n(2549), {
            volumeStep: .1,
            seekStep: 15,
            enableMute: !0,
            enableFullscreen: !0,
            enableNumbers: !0
        }),
```

Unfortunately I am an absolute newbie in JavaScript, so it's really hard for me to understand what exactly goes on in the methods. I already researched quite a bit to find out if that is even possible but didn't really find a good solution or definitive answer since I suppose that it varies from case to case.

Thanks in advance,
Andi

Edit: I already tried with the developer tools of Chrome and Firefox, but simply setting the variable to 3 is not working and with Tampermonkey I can create an alert which works on the main site of udemy.com but not on the video player site. So that's already a problem...

Comment: You could probably just go into your browser console, paste the above definition of `f`, but change the seekStep, then run it. I don't know what that `n` function does, but providing it doesn't do any weird side effects, that should work.

Comment: depends if it is global or not

Comment: Can you overwrite the `seekBackward` function? you could overwrite `f` as well but this function name probably changes more often.)

Comment: Roland Starke: you mean the function o? It gives back "undefined" if I try to overwrite the seekStep value in it.

Comment: Carcigenicate: If I do that it gives me
"Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1"

Comment: The usual approach is to use Fiddler or similar MitM proxy and set a rule to replace the text. If you insist on doing it in the browser, it's complicated: you need to fetch the script text via XHR, replace the value, fetch the page text via XHR, replace the original script link with your patched version and rewrite current page via document.write

Comment: wOxxOm: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll make sure to work myself into Fiddler. To be honest: I don't understand the second approach. And is it correct that these are only approaches that work temporarily or is the Fiddler one something permanent that runs every time I have Fiddler open?
Is replacing the Javascript file with a Tampermonkey script an option?

Comment: "Replacing file with a Tampermonkey script" is the 2nd option I described.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the script text, replace the value, fetch the page source, replace the original script link with your patched version and rewrite current page via document.write.

Optionally store the patched script in localStorage (I think it's better than GM_getValue because Tampermonkey injects those alongside the script so I'd rather not encumber it with a 300kB value).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          patch seekStep
// @match         https://www.udemy.com/*
// @run-at        document-start
// ==/UserScript==

window.stop();

const SCRIPT_URL = 'https://www.udemy.com/staticx/udemy/js/webpack/' +
  'videojs-open-source-package.8c14010d78dd1966a713.js';

Promise.all([
  fetch(location.href, {credentials: 'include'}).then(r => r.text()),
  localStorage.patchedScript ||
    fetch(SCRIPT_URL, {credentials: 'include'}).then(r => r.text()).then(text => {
      text = text.replace(/(seekStep):\d+/, '$1:3');
      localStorage.patchedScript = text;
      return text;
    }),
]).then(([html, script]) => {
  document.open();
  html = html.replace(
    /<script[^>]*?src=["'][^"'>]*?videojs-open-source-package[^>]+>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/,
    `<script>${script}</script>`);
  document.write(html);
  document.close();
});
```

I'm replacing the script reference using a regexp since it's fast on a large and complicated page source, but feel free to use the proper [DOMParser](http://devdocs.io/dom/domparser) method if you like.

Don't forget to supply a real URL pattern in `@match` instead of the entire site covered in the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the work! But somehow I am always logged out when the script is active and can't login. It just shows the loading animation but I can't login. Any idea why that is the case? For now I can't see if it works since I don't get to the video player.

Comment: I would have to create an account there to investigate the reason, but it's a separate issue.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that `fetch` needs an explicit parameter to include current credentials, see the updated code.

Comment: Alright, that solved the login issue. But unfortunately it still only skips forward or back 15 seconds.

Comment: It means the script is not working for you so you should debug it. Of the top of my head, maybe there are several occurrences that should be replaced by adding `g` flag in regexp.